# C++ i am confuse on how to write formula for code c and I

Tags: visual-c++

1. Write a program that displays water bills. Your program should prompt the user to enter an integer account number, a character use code, and a real number representing the gallons of water used. The output from your program should include the account number, message indicating the type of usage, and the amount of money due from the user. Draw a flowchart for your program.

The water rates vary depending on the type of usage. A code of H means home use, a code of C means commercial use, and a code of I means industrial use. Any other code value should be treated as an error. Water rates are computed as follows:

Code H: $5.00 plus $0.005 per gallon

Code C:     $1000.00 for the first 4 million gallons used plus
        $0.025 for each additional gallon used

Code I: $1000.00 if usage does not exceed 4 million gallons
        $2000.00 is usage is between 4 million and 10 million gallons
        $3000.00 is 10 million gallons or more

```
cout << " Enter your account number" << endl;
cin >> account;

cout << " Enter your code (h, c or i): h means home, c means commercial use and i means industrial use" << endl;
cin >> code;

cout << " Enter the number of gallons of water used" << endl;
cin >> gallon;


return 0;
} 

void company() { 
    switch (code) {

        case 'H': case 'h':
            total = (0.0005*gallon) + 5;
            cout, , " your total gallons of water is" << endl;

            break;

        case 'C': case 'c':


        case 'I': case 'i':
```

Comment: So, where did you get stuck? What is your concrete issue?

Comment: I am confuse on code c i don't really know how to write it as well as code i

Comment: Edit your code into the question, not in the comments.

Comment: ok I fix it now , this is basically what I have so far

Comment: Thank you for fixing it for me I am new on this site, yea I am like stuck in case C and i I know I have to write a if statement in case I but i don't know how to go by writing it but for case c I don't really know what to do

Answer (score 0):

This is simple translation of the human readable text.

for code c, :

```
total = 1000; // 1000 dollars in any case
int remaining_gallons_to_pay = gallon - 4000000; // the first 4 million are already paid for
if(remaining_gallons_to_pay > 0) {  // maybe they used less than 4 million, if so, their problem
    total = total + (remaining_gallons_to_pay * 0.025);
}
break;
```

for code i:

```
if (gallon <= 4000000) { // 'does not exceed' means less or equal
    total = 1000;
}
else if (gallon <= 10000000) { // cannot be 4 million or less, already checked, but "between 4 million and 10 million", is this inclusive 10 million? I assumed so for this statement...
    total = 2000;
}
else { // so, it must be over 10 million
    total = 3000;
}
break;
```

As you are using the switch ... case statement, you have another option to your disposal: `default`. All cases you have not dealt with - and ended with `break` - land here. So you are left with adding

```
default : cout << "Code error"
```

into your switch-block.